# Resize amp-img manually

Tags: jquery, image, iframe

I need to access an amp-img inside an iFrame to change the width property. I've tried searching by ID and traversing down from the iFrame, but the content is not available. Is there a way I can access this? The img is brought in from an Ad script which I don't have access to change the size there, so manually is my only option. I've waited until the window has loaded, so the elements are definitely available.

```
$("amp-img") // not working

$("iframe").first() // can't seem to get below this level in the watcher in dev tools.
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: As you state the iframe is part of an advert script, it's highly unlikely you will be able to do what you ask as you cannot amend the content of cross-domain iframes from the parent window for obvious security reasons.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought just wanted to double-check if there was an alternative